# SLACK-MODALS Custom Leave/permission approval or deny custom app

Tags: slack, slack-api, bolts-framework, slack-block-kit

Can anyone please help me by giving me an idea on how to build a custom **slack app** for leave/permission approval or denial. Any suggestions will very useful.Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What do you intend to do? How much have you already done? Where are you stuck?

Comment: List of App Templates using Block Kit : https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?template=1

Comment: Hi @SuyashGaur thank you for the reply. I'm trying to build **slack** custom private app for my company which on filling and submitting the form should go to HR for approval/deny of permission. Till now i have not done anything because im very new to this. I just tried to create app by looking at the documentation from slack website.

Comment: @SuyashGaur, yea  after using that template how to make that buttons to do their respective job? like approve / deny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, you can start looking into the examples provided by Slack.

**Developing approval workflows**

1. https://api.slack.com/best-practices/blueprints/approval-workflows
2. https://github.com/slackapi/template-announcement-approvals

Further documentation:

 https://github.com/slackapi